# How to implement Federated Authentication for server processes communicating with each other

Tags: claims-based-identity, federated-identity, thinktecture-ident-server

I'm currently using Thinktecture's Identity Server as a security token service to handle the issuing of tokens based on username and password claims.  This fits perfectly for a scenario where the authenticating client is an actual user authenticating against a web application for instance, but I'm now interested in scenario for when the authenticating party happens to be an independent process on the server that needs to establish a security token to pass to another server process.  I'm ideally after a few pieces of advice here:
1. Is this a valid approach to authentication for server processes communicating with each other?
2. What if I were to move one of the server processes to a different machine talking across a TCP boundary instead perhaps?  Is this approach still valid.
3. What ClaimTypes would I use for authentication of the process?  And is the Thinktecture Identity Server happy to authenticate against these?  I assume I'll probably have to write a custom authentication extension to it to do so...

Thanks very much,
Clint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of IdentityServer's authentication protocols is the "simple http" -- you pass in credentials and get back a token. This might be what you want.

Oh, there's also the WS-Trust endpoints as well.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes - I'm currently manually requesting the token for a username/password credential as in Dominick's post: http://leastprivilege.com/2012/11/16/wcf-and-identity-in-net-4-5-external-authentication-with-ws-trust/
I thought it didn't really make sense for server processes to identify themselves with a username/password credential though.  I've since started trying to work out how to use a certificate as a credential (seemed more logical for the known machine to use a "something-I-have" means of authentication instead of "something-I-know".

Comment: I've hit an issue with this though as detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138715/how-to-specify-a-certificate-as-the-credentials-for-a-wstrustchannel-with-thinkt