# How to specify a certificate as the credentials for a wsTrustChannel with Thinktecture IdentityServer

Tags: federated-identity, thinktecture-ident-server, ws-trust

I would have thought that one could basically switch the client credentials from this:

```
var clientCredentials = new ClientCredentials();
clientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "MyUserName"
clientCredentials.UserName.Password = "MyPassword"
```

to:

```
var clientCredentials = new ClientCredentials();
clientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = myX509Certificate;
```

and then create a wsTrustChannel to get a security token.

```
wsTrustChannelFactory.SetCredentials(clientCredentials);

var channel = _wsTrustChannelFactory.CreateChannel(new EndpointAddress(endpointAddress));

var token = channel.Issue(new RequestSecurityToken
{
    TokenType = tokenType,
    AppliesTo = new EndpointReference(realm),
    RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,
    KeyType = KeyTypes.Bearer
}, out requestSecurityTokenResponse);
```

The username and password work fine, just using the certificate complains that there's no UserName specified.  I was under the impression that the token issuer would look up the associated user from the certificate.  Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT - Double whoops!  I was using a UserNameWSTrustBinding for the endpoint, when I should have obviously been using a CertificateWSTrustBinding.  Making this change solved this issue.

---

EDIT - I thought I'd solved this as below, but it's still asking for a Username even on this endpoint.  Any ideas?

---

Whoops!  Worked this out about 5 minutes after I posted the above question.  There's a different endpoint address for the certificate authentication:

```
https://servername/identityserver/issue/wstrust/mixed/certificate
```

instead of

```
https://servername/identityserver/issue/wstrust/mixed/username
```